# HTML SVG with viewBox and preserveAspectRatio xMinYMin meet incorrect shape in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I want an SVG to be a 4:1 width:height size, with the absolute size changing according to browser window size. I need the aspect ratio of the coordinate space within the SVG to be 1:1.

The following achieves exactly what I want in Firefox, showing a blue SVG background with 4:1 ratio (eg. 1000 x 250px, depending on window size). However, in Chrome, the ratio is not observed and the SVG/visible background is eg. 1000 x 570px.

```
<body>
    <div id="svgdiv" style="background:AliceBlue; max-Width:100%">
        <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 100 25">
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is this a bug in Chrome, or have I misunderstood the usage? How can I obtain what I want in Chrome?

Comment: Bug in new Chrome, didn't happen in Chrome a version ago.

Comment: I can verify that the problem still occurs in Windows Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m.  Has anyone found a workaround yet?